# Image inserted within svg not displaying in older Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, safari

I have the following structure on my website, which should display an image within an svg tag.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <g class="image-map-container" transform="translate(143, 221.5) scale(1)"><image xlink:href="https://source.unsplash.com/random"></image></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

As you can probably imagine, I use this structure in combination with JS to scale and move the image within a set container.

This approach works great in Chrome, newer versions of Firefox and Safari 13.1, but in Safari 12.1 and in Firefox version 68 and downwards, the image isn't displayed at all.

What could be the reason for this?

I created the following snippet for reproduction purposes:
https://codepen.io/pasa/pen/RwaRrKm

Comment: Try giving the image height and width attributes.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well that works but that seems to defeat the purpose of scale doesn't it?

Comment: I should probably mention that I use ``d3.zoom()`` for the scaling like that:


this.interactionMap.translation.x = d3.event.transform.x;

this.interactionMap.translation.y = d3.event.transform.y;

this.interactionMap.scale = d3.event.transform.k;

Comment: Yes, that's why the SVG 2 specification makes them optional and why new browser versions implemented that specification change.